# SLComposeViewController on Twitter: how to detect duplicate post

Tags: twitter, ios6, slcomposeviewcontroller

I'm using Social Framework on iOS 6 for Twitter integration, using the following code :

```
SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
controller.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
      // cancelled
    } else if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
      // done
    } else {
      // unknown
    }
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
};
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

If the user set the same tweet message as one of its old message, I get a popup "The tweet "xxx" is a duplicate and cannot be sent." but the completion handler result value is  still SLComposeViewControllerResultDone. Is there a way to know if a tweet has **really** be sent ?
It seems that the same behaviour is happening for TWTweetComposeViewController.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In iOS 5 twitter integration,

TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult just has 2 options

When user selects done -- TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone

When user selects cancel -- TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancel

This result doesn't depend on the tweets updated by apple in background. If the tweets fail while updating it shows an alert.

SO i suggest do not implement any custom pop-up for success or failure. As apple itself implemented indications for success/failure tweet updates. On success it plays a sound & on failure a pop-up with reason.

Comment: The suggestion makes sense for UI notifications, but it still means there's a gap in the Social.Framework API if you want to perform some action _only_ if the tweet was posted successfully.

Comment: @JeremyWiebe So there's no way to know if a tweet was posted successfully, using the Social.Framework?

Comment: On looking at the API again it looks like you can leverage performRequestWithHandler: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWRequestClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_10  I haven't tried this so I'm not sure it will be exactly what's needed.  Looks promising.